# Data Jumbeling in csv file

Tags: python, csv, pyqt

I have application in PyQt. On submit, All the combobox and line edit and qplaintextedit and the info from qtable widget are added into a list. The list pastes data into csv file and refreshes the fields that are present. And new information gets loaded into qtablewidget area. Next again information from all the fields below+qtablewidget information is added into csv file. But, the information in csv files are getting jumbled. qtablewidget information must have information of fields which are given below. But it gets interchanged. Any Suggestions ?

[image]

```html
if os.path.isfile("Rts.csv") is True:

                    with open('Rts.csv', 'r') as fo:
                
                        reader = csv.reader(fo, delimiter = ',')
                        ncol = len(next(reader))
                        data = list(reader)
                        row_count = len(data)

                
                        if staticVariable.static_count_clicked <= row_count:

                            print staticVariable.static_count_clicked

                            main =  data[staticVariable.static_count_clicked]

                            print main

                            data = []

                            xdata = [str(da), str(compout), str(locout), str(resout), str(geotxt), str(landtxt), str(suggestxt), str(remarkstxt)]

                            data = [main + xdata]

                            print data

                            if os.path.isfile("rts_output.csv") is True:
                            
                                with open('rts_output.csv', 'a') as fp:
                            
                                    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter = ',' )
                            
                                    awrite = a.writerows(data)   

                                fp.close()


            
                            for var in range(0, ncol):                                                  
                                self.dadis.setItem(0, var, QTableWidgetItem(main[var]))


                            pbvar = staticVariable.static_count_clicked
                            print pbvar

                            self.no_cases.setText(str(pbvar) + " Cases done out of - " + str(row_count))

                            staticVariable.static_count_clicked += 1
                            staticVariable.static_main_clicked += 1


                    fp.close()
```

Comment: please could you post the code you are using to generate the CSV file?

Comment: please add csv file and code